# AWS Discovery only tries 3 ports 5701, 5702 & 5703 while joining cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, hazelcast

I have a application which internally uses hazelcast and application is deployed in AWS as a docker container. It works fine when I start my docker container and expose host port 5701/5702/5703 mapped to each of docker container internal port 5701. (i.e `docker run .............. -p 5701:5701` or `docker run .............. -p 5702:5701` or `docker run .............. -p 5703:5701`). I am also setting public address accordingly like `$DOCKER_HOST:5701` or  `$DOCKER_HOST:5702` or `$DOCKER_HOST:5703`.

But when I start my containers mapped to any other host ports than these ports then it's not joining the cluster. Looks like AWS discovery is only looking for private instances IPs and then only check for 5701/5702/5703 port in these private IPs.

Can someone please tell how to configure in AWS discovery to scan for more ports ?  FYI am using `hazelcast-all-3.7.4.jar`

With TCPDiscovery we can specify auto increment and increment count, but with docker auto increment doesn't make sense as each docker container will be it's isolated runtime with just one port mapped/exposed to host (in Dockerfile  `EXPOSE 5701`).

Here is my sample `hazelcast-spring.xml` configuration file.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:hz="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
              http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring/hazelcast-spring.xsd">


    <hz:hazelcast id="sampleHazelcastInstance">
        <hz:config>
            <!-- Hazelcast Instance Name -->
            <hz:instance-name>${sample.hz.instance.name}</hz:instance-name>
            <hz:group name="${sample.hz.group.name}" password="${sample.hz.group.pwd}"/>
            <hz:management-center  enabled="${sample.hz.management.center.enabled:false}" url="${sample.hz.management.center.url:}" update-interval="5"/>

            <hz:properties>
                <hz:property name="hazelcast.shutdownhook.enabled">${sample.hz.shutdownhook.enabled:false}</hz:property>
                <hz:property name="hazelcast.icmp.enabled">${sample.hz.icmp.enabled:true}</hz:property>
                <hz:property name="hazelcast.socket.bind.any">${sample.hz.socket.bind.any:true}</hz:property>
                <hz:property name="hazelcast.socket.server.bind.any">${sample.hz.socket.server.bind.any:true}</hz:property>
                <hz:property name="hazelcast.socket.client.bind.any">${sample.hz.socket.client.bind.any:true}</hz:property>
                <hz:property name="hazelcast.max.no.heartbeat.seconds">${sample.hz.max.no.heartbeat.seconds:30}</hz:property>
                <hz:property name="hazelcast.client.max.no.heartbeat.seconds">${sample.hz.client.max.no.heartbeat.seconds:30}</hz:property>
                <hz:property name="hazelcast.logging.type">${sample.hz.logging.type:slf4j}</hz:property>
                <hz:property name="hazelcast.local.localAddress">${sample.hz.localAddress}</hz:property>
            </hz:properties>

            <hz:network port="${sample.hz.network.port:5701}" port-auto-increment="${sample.hz.network.port.auto.increment:false}" 
                public-address="${sample.hz.publicAddress}">
                <hz:outbound-ports>
                    <hz:ports>0</hz:ports>
                </hz:outbound-ports>
                <hz:join>
                    <hz:multicast enabled="${sample.hz.multicast.enabled:false}" />
                    <hz:tcp-ip connection-timeout-seconds="${sample.hz.tcpip.conn.timeout:30}" enabled="${sample.hz.tcpip.enabled:false}" />
                    <hz:aws enabled="${sample.hz.aws.enabled:true}" 
                        access-key="${sample.hz.aws.access.key}"
                        secret-key="${sample.hz.aws.secret.key}"
                        iam-role="${sample.hz.aws.iam.role}"
                        region="${sample.hz.aws.region:us-east-1}"
                        host-header="${sample.hz.aws.host.header:ec2.amazonaws.com}"
                        security-group-name="${sample.hz.aws.security.group.name}"
                        tag-key="${sample.hz.aws.tag.key}"
                        tag-value="${sample.hz.aws.tag.value}" 
                        connection-timeout-seconds="${sample.hz.aws.conn.timeout:30}" />
                </hz:join>
                <hz:reuse-address>true</hz:reuse-address>
            </hz:network>

            <!-- Hazelcast Distributed Map configuration -->

</beans>
```

Comment: You mentioned this is deployed in a Docker container. Are you using the ECS Container service, or your own Docker installation?

Comment: tried with both ECS container as well manually spun with docker run... same result, this infact it is due to limitation of AWS discovery it just identifies the private ips of all AWS instances and hazelcast scans only starting with 5701 when port is missing in the address. So that explains why it's not working, it's a serious limitation not be able to pass starting scan ports instead of default 5701 when it's not explicitly specified. Opened a issue https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/9664

Comment: you should probably open this directly in the hazelcast aws repo: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-aws